# Using args to find list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I'm trying to return a list of tuples using *args, and without using the `zip` function. Here's what I have so far. I'm a bit confused over how to use args in my code. Should I be sublists?

```
def merge_wrap_n(*args):
    sub_size = max(map(len, args))
    tupleList = []
    for i in range(sub_size): 
        tupleList.append((args[i%len(args)])) 
    return tupleList
```

Testing on:

```
merge_wrap_n([1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6]) == [(1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6)]
```

Comment: What is the current result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need two loops, one from `0` to `sub_size-1`, which you have, and another nested one to loop over each element in args (used as list comprehension below):

```
def merge_wrap_n(*args):
    sub_size = max(map(len, args))
    tupleList = []
    for i in range(sub_size):
        tup = tuple([sub_lst[i%len(sub_lst)] for sub_lst in args])
        tupleList.append(tup)
    return tupleList

>>> merge_wrap_n([1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6])
[(1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6)]
```